# How to find a 10x10x3 numpy array within a 1000x1000x3 numpy array (fast)?

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering the following:

I have a 10x10x3 and a 1000x1000x3 numpy array.
I want to check if the smaller array can be found within the bigger array (and where). This is pretty easy with 2 for loops, but that solution is *very* slow:

```py
H, W, _ = big.shape
h, w, _ = small.shape

for i in range(H - h + 1):
    for j in range(W - w + 1):
        if np.array_equal(big[i:i+h, j:j+w, :], small):
            print(i,j)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to vectorize this? Or a way to write this routine faster?

Comment: 1000x1000x3 or 100x100x3? Which is it?

Comment: And what are the values like? In particular, how many unique/duplicate values are there?

Comment: @JérômeRichard one problem of `convolve` is if e.g. the small array is full of zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** see "**approach #4**" below, using a second look at `sliding_window_view`. That's more than 640x faster than the OP's Python nested loops.

**Notes:**

1. For consistency, in all the approaches below, I am using a `1000,1000,3` array for  `big` (even though the question has evolved from 1000 to 100).
2. All the solutions I give also search in the 3rd dimension (e.g. if `big ~ 1000,1000,5` and `small ~ 10,10,3`)

## Setup

```py
def problem(n=1000):
    big = np.ones((n, n, 3))
    small = np.zeros((10, 10, 3))

    # plug small at three locations, two of them overlapping
    s0, s1, s2 = small.shape
    i0, i1, i2 = 2, 3, 0
    big[i0:i0+s0, i1:i1+s1, i2:i2+s2] = small
    
    i0, i1, i2 = 3, 4, 0
    big[i0:i0+s0, i1:i1+s1, i2:i2+s2] = small
    
    i0, i1, i2 = 10, 15, 0
    big[i0:i0+s0, i1:i1+s1, i2:i2+s2] = small

    return big, small

# for all below, we use:
big, small = problem(1000)
```

## Approach #1: `sliding_window_view`

A way that avoids the problem I flagged in comments to the `correlate2d` solution is to use `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`:

```py
# 2. finding the locations of the small array

from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view
>>> np.c_[np.where(((sliding_window_view(big, small.shape) - small)**2).sum((-1, -2, -3)) == 0)]
array([[ 2,  3,  0],
       [ 3,  4,  0],
       [10, 15,  0]])
```

In terms of speed, this is only 5x faster than the OP's approach. We can surely do better.

## Approach #2: convolution against a prime kernel

**Edit: this idea is actually wrong; one can always get false positives.**

The idea was to use convolution, but attempting to take some care to avoid false positives (e.g. if `small = zero`).

I had thought of using a kernel made of primes, of same size as `small`. Then, I thought that the convolution of `small, ker` was a unique value that can be obtained only if all the elements are exactly the same as `small`. But this is false. Even using only integers, we can easily build counter-examples:

`[2, 1, 0] ✱ [1, 3, 5] == 13 == [1, 2, 2], [1, 3, 5]` (where `✱` denotes convolution).

I am leaving the code below, but it should not be used.

```py
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve


def conv_find(big, small):
    '''do not use: can give false hits'''
    n = np.prod(small.shape)
    
    # https://t5k.org/howmany.html:
    # p(n) <= n (ln n + ln ln n - 1 + 1.8 ln ln n / ln n)  if n >= 13
    l_n = np.log(n)
    N = int(np.ceil(n * (l_n + np.log(np.log(n - 1)) + 1.8 * np.log(l_n) / l_n) if n >= 13 else 53.77))
    
    ker = np.array(primesfrom2to(N)[:n]).reshape(small.shape)

    indices = np.c_[np.where(np.isclose(
        fftconvolve(big, ker, 'valid'),
        fftconvolve(small, ker, 'valid')))
    ]
    return indices
```

(`primesfrom2to(N)` is one of many functions finding primes up to `N`; I use the one given in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/758174)).

Example:

```py
>>> conv_find(big, small)
array([[ 2,  3,  0],
       [ 3,  4,  0],
       [10, 15,  0]])
```

Now, the timing is a bit better:

```py
>>> big.shape, small.shape
((1000, 1000, 3), (10, 10, 3))

%timeit conv_find(big, small)
437 ms ± 2.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit op_find(big, small)
3.29 s ± 2.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So now we have a 7.4x speedup, with the risk of accidental hits (which we could filter down with an actual equality check). I believe we can still do better.

## Approach #3: Numba to the rescue!

```py
from numba import njit

@njit
def _nb_find(big, small):
    H, W, L = big.shape
    h, w, l = small.shape
    ix = np.zeros((H - h + 1, W - w + 1, L - l + 1))
    x0 = small[0,0,0]
    for i in range(H - h + 1):
        for j in range(W - w + 1):
            for k in range(L - l + 1):
                if big[i, j, k] == x0 and np.array_equal(big[i:i+h, j:j+w, k:k+l], small):
                    ix[i, j, k] = 1
    return ix

def nb_find(big, small):
    return np.c_[np.nonzero(_nb_find(big, small))]
```

The first part of the test (`big[i, j, k] == x0`) avoids calling `np.array_equal` and gives us an additional 50x speedup.

Now, the timing is:

```py
%timeit nb_find(big, small)
8.96 ms ± 72.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

That's a 367x speedup from the `op_find`, and 48x faster than my second solution above (using `fftconvolve`).

## Approach #4: `sliding_window_view` revisited

Based on the result that just checking the first element (approach #3) gives us a nice speedup, we can revisit our `sliding_window_view` approach, to do this with pure `numpy` (without need for `numba`).

```py
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

def slide_find2(big, small):
    z = sliding_window_view(big, small.shape)
    ix = np.where(z[:, :, :, 0, 0, 0] == small[0,0,0])
    return np.c_[ix][np.all(z[ix] == small, axis=(-3, -2, -1))]
```

Note: as per @JérômeRichard's comment, we can identify the rarest element in both `small` and `large`, and use that one instead of `0,0,0` in the function above. Right now trying to keep this simple.

The speed now is:

```py
%timeit slide_find2(big, small)
# 5.14 ms ± 44.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

That is 640x faster than the OP's loop.

Comment: Interesting solutions. The Numba code can be improved but it might be enough for the OP. One optimisation is to locate key values in the small array so to skip part of the big array similar to the Boyer-Moore algorithm, but this is not trivial to do and it depends of the actual values in the array not provided by the OP. Another optimisation which is trivial is to use multiple threads (using `prange` and `parallel=True`). This assume the caller of the function do not already use multiple threads or processes though.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: yes indeed, I was thinking about this as well. The approach #4 in my edited answer would allow to do that relatively easily: select the rarest element (count in `small` times count in `big`) and use the first index of its position(s) in `small`, instead of `0,0,0` above.

Comment: Just realized that my idea of using a kernel of primes still doesn't prevent possible false positives. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Approach #4 is just pure elegance! Thank you for this beautiful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using scipy's [`correlate2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html#scipy.signal.correlate2d), you could do something like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import correlate2d

big = np.zeros((100, 100, 3))
small = np.ones((10, 10, 3))

big[23:33, 45:55, :] = small

def find_location(big, small):
    # final dimension
    fd = big.shape[-1]

    # locations of sub-array for each slice
    for i in range(fd):
        # get the expected cross-correlation if the sub-array exactly matches
        expected = correlate2d(small[:, :, i], small[:, :, i], "valid").flatten()[0]
        c = correlate2d(big[:, :, i], small[:, :, i], "valid")

        if i == 0:
            locations = [loc.tolist() for loc in np.argwhere(c == expected)]
        else:
            # check if any of the locations match between slices
            newlocations = [loc.tolist() for loc in np.argwhere(c == expected)]
            for loc in list(locations):
                if loc not in newlocations:
                    locations.remove(loc)

    return locations


print(find_location(big, small))
```

Comment: but if you have `ones` for `big` and `zeros` for `small`, you wrongly get all locations.

Comment: How much faster is that?

Comment: For the arrays in my example, using `%timeit` my method runs in 10.9 ms ± 417 µs per loop, versus 46.6 ms ± 1.36 ms per loop for the OPs method.

Comment: If `big` is actually 1000x1000x3, my method's run time is 932 ms ± 46.8 ms per loop versus 6.06 s ± 555 ms per loop for the OPs method.

Comment: @KellyBundy I've fixed it (by adding `"valid"` into the `correlate2d` call, so that it gives the expected values for the location.